# git: show which files have changed between kernel 3.18.6 and 3.18.7

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, git, version-control

I have checked out linux kernel git repository

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
```

I know how to use `git log`, `git show` and similar commands to see changes/commits in the main kernel tree. For my particular purpose, I am however only interested in changes of the kernel tree 3.18.

How can I see only changes relating to 3.18 ?

How can I see, for example, which files have been changed between `3.18.6` and `3.18.7` ?

Comment: `git diff --stat 3.18.6 3.18.7` Assumming `3.18.7` and `3.18.7` or either tags or branches on that gir repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather clone this [git](http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git). And then do `git diff --stat`

```
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git`
$ cd linux-stable/
$ git diff --stat v3.18.6 v3.18.7
```

Comment: what repository is that ?

Comment: That is the stable linux public repo. Looking at Torvalds repo might not be same as looking at this repo.

Comment: I did not know there are more repos. How did you find it? Do you know where I could read more about which repo is for what purpose ?

Comment: If you browse https://git.kernel.org/cgit/ There are like 100s of repos. You can even search on the upper right corner

Comment: but there are several repos called "stable". How do I know this is the one I need ?

Comment: If you see other stable ones those are by some developers. And frankly somone told me once about this repo and I just keep it back in my mind.